# How to list filename with all existing extensions

Tags: git, bash

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this one. 
I need an output in form:

```
home/Documents/some-cool-doc 
.docx 
.html 
.js
```

Comment: is the formatting important or you want the list of file with same name ? Please give more information about your goal

Comment: please clarify the question. I don't understand what you're asking for or trying to do

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
ls -Xp | grep -Eo "\.[^/]+$" | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

First be sure to use an [associative array](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#associative_bash_4).

#### Pseudo-code

```
For each file in directory
  store the filename,
  append the file extension to the value

For each filename indexed
  print the filename and associated extensions
```

#### Codes

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A filenames

for file in *; do
    filename="${file%.*}"
    ext="${file##*.}"

    printf "$filename . $ext\n"
    filenames["$filename"]="${filenames["$filename"]}"$ext",";
done;

for filename in "${!filenames[@]}"; do
    printf "$filename \n\t ${filenames["$filename"]}\n";
done
```

#### Output

```
content-requirements-example
         zip,
user-journey.pptx
         zip,
Ergonomic-criteria-for-the-evaluation-of-human-computer-interfaces-J.M.-Christian-Bastien,-Dominique-L.-Scapin
         pdf,
UX_Curve_templates_eng_new
         doc,pdf,
```

### Drawback

There is probably some corner cases, feel free to adapt.